# Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' for Entity Framework Core asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have a field inside my dataSet from postgress = jsonField (type: JSonb).

My dataset object looks something like this:

```
dataset:
{
id:"221dsfsedf-234mfidu-ndsufds89",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "24/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val4",
"b":"val5",
"c":"val6"
} 
},
{
id:"221dsfsedf-23728837hjhu-ndsufds89",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "22/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val7",
"b":"val2",
"c":"val9"
} 
},
{
id:"2564fsedf-234mfidu-ndh783839",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "23/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val9",
"b":"val21",
"c":"val34"
} 
}
```

To search any value from jsonField, I am using below given LinQ query, which is working fine.

```
request.Query ="val5"
dataset = dataset.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(s => JObject.Parse(s.Attributes).Values()
             .Any(j => j.ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(request.Query.ToLower(), StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0))
                .AsQueryable();
```

But when I go next step and applying paging:

```
var page = await dataset.Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
```

it is throwing an error:

> The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

For workaround I am able to fix the issue with below solution by converting async operation to task await operation.

```
var resultPage = dataset.Skip(request.Skip)
                        .Take(request.Take)
                        .ToArray();
var page = await Task.FromResult(resultPage);
```

However, as per async programming, its not correct approach.

Looking for solution for my actual issue regarding `IAsyncQueryProvider` or any improvements in linQ query. And if its not feasible, want to understand in my workaround, why it worked with await task.fromresult  and not worked with async page as above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `JObject.Parse`, but a [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations). Then you don't need `AsEnumerable()` and you don't lose the "contact" with the EF query provider.

Comment: You cannot apply EF Core's async methods over `IQueryable` that was created from `IEnumerable`. It is also has not sense, because there is no IO operations.

Comment: @GertArnold, actually *value conversion* is what stops EF Core from translating queries.

Comment: @Svyatoslav You're right if you mean that predicates won't be translated into SQL (in this case). The value conversion itself is a configured client-side conversion while materializing a query result. But it wouldn't help much here because the predicate still can't translated to make paging happen database-side. This is an example of a data model that hampers efficient querying by EF. Here [native JSON querying](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/) should be used.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have already prepared PGSQL query for my requirement: ` select * from app.dataset where array_to_string( array(select value from jsonb_each_text(jsonField)), ' ') like '%searchthisVal%';`  but didn't got jsonb_each_text for EF core LINQ query. Please guid or help to convert this sql query to LINQ query .

Comment: Check available [JSON Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html) and actually there is possibility to map [table-value functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function)

Comment: As my json is dynamic over here- I am not using Json mapping or table valued function. And accessing json values only to search data.

Comment: I have changed my code to iterate each field and match value as below:
```foreach (var key in fieldHeaders)
 {
 var searchQuery = "{\"" + key + "\": \"" + query + "\"}"; // e.g. query = val9
 set = dataSet.AsNoTracking();
 set = dataset.Where(s => EF.Functions.JsonContains(r.jsonField, searchQuery));
 
 if (set.Count() > 0) break;
}
```But in this case I am not able search Partial string or substring. any advice on how to use like operator here.